# How to convert Base64 encoded pkcs12 content to java.security.PrivateKey?

Tags: java, google-api-java-client, private-key, google-admin-sdk, pkcs#12

I'm consuming Google Directory API via service account and I received a `pkcs12` key at service account creation.

Google does support two different ways to use this  as taking the key as `java.io.File` or `java.security.PrivateKey` and for PoC, I have used first way which is creating `GoogleCredential` object using the `java.io.File`,

```
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER))
                .setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountUser)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(serviceAccountPrivateKeyFile)
                .build();
```

It's working as expected but in my actual use case i cannot rely on filesystem so i cannot use first method. So i wanted to implement actual use case using second way which is using `java.security.PrivateKey` and would look like following when its done.

```
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER))
            .setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountUser)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(serviceAccountPrivateKey)
            .build();
```

Im my use case, i need make possible to upload the private key and store it in the database with base64 encoded. Now i need to pass that content of `pkcs12` key and create the `Googlecredential` object. To do i think the second option is the most suited way, but couldn't find any example to create java.security.PrivateKey from the base64 encoded content of the uploaded key.

Is that possible to create `java.security.PrivateKey` object from a base64 encoded content of `pkcs12` key?

Or is there any other way around to achieve my usecase?

Thanks in advance

DarRay

Answer (score 0):

java.securty.KeyStore takes any InputStream for the load() method, so you could create this using whatever method you have of obtaining the .p12 bytes.  Here's an alternate method I used.  While this is still using a file for the .p12 bytes, you could bring in a ByteArrayInputStream or any InputStream subclass:

```
    private PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromP12() {
        // Google p12 files all have "notasecret" as the pass and "privatekey" as the PK name
        String p12p = "notasecret";    // not cool!  Change this before exporting your .p12
        try {
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            // This is where you'd adjust to bring in your .p12 bytes or chars
            // as an input stream.  Passwords are a char array!
            keystore.load(
                this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                        .getResourceAsStream("the.p12"),
                p12p.toCharArray());
            // This key name is fixed by Google, but could be changed
            PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey("privatekey",
                p12p.toCharArray());
            return key;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception while trying to obtain private key",e);
            return null;
        } 

    }
```